# How to deal with a constructor in interfaces and ensure the same access to data in different implementations?

Tags: typescript, oop

I am working on a project that requires a notification to be send whenever an error occurs. (I know there are tools for this but that is not relevant for didactic purposes.)

```
interface ErrorNotifier{
   NotifyInternally(): void
}

class EmailErrorNotifier{
   constructor(type, errors){
     this.type = type
     this.errors = errors
   }
   notifyInternally(){
   // send email with the type and errors etc
   }
}
```

However, when I implement another instance of an `ErrorNotifier` (let's say an PhoneErrorNotifier, that sends a text message) how do I ensure that in the constructor of that class also the type and the errors are passed and are available for the `notifyInternally` method? Should I use an abstract class? Forgive me for my ignorance but I am trying to learn more OOP!

Comment: Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKJSgeygOU2YGYaAbwFgAoZavAmATwElxoQ4Abd+gCgEoAuZADdMwACaVqyMPQAOEQXBD0A3JOrQsUAM6CAriADWITAHcQlAL6VKCdnG3a0AWzjB26LbULEoyYM6y7BDOEOBOntjeRKTqyAD08ciMgcGhLGL+LLCIKDDYSE5gABbATnYORZjIxXBCEHGJ0sUQ2ihCcFDAcABGwU5KmSUo0UzZbJw8vMihJZhiAHRxsnp9wAjImti6yEqqy6vs69JyCrvKahRxCJgg2mBQeghg2Nwy8orKADSbGNuf9F45CoUmaZQW7xQAF4TvJLqCwdoFlsdMgYSjtHFrFcQcgVmsNqNmJAoBMuHxBCJxMgSMhsZYgA) what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you what the benefit of doing is this over an abstract class and what are the downsides?

Comment: to add to what @MikeS. said: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKJSgeygOU2YGYaAHgBUAaNAPmQG8BYAKGVbwJgE8BJcaEOABtBnABQBKAFzIAbpmAATZq2RhOABwjSyAbmWtoWKAGdpqZgF9mzBILjHjaALZxgg9EfaFiUchVS0wE7qghBOEOCOHtheRKSUNPT6yAD0KcjcwaHhfArIoJCwiCgw2EiOYAAWwI629hWYyJVwMhDJaaqVEMYoMnBQwHAARqGOcCB5VSixPHxQAsJi4sjhVZgKAHTJ6gCuI8AIyIbYpmh6LKy7+4dqmtrnyQiYIMZgUDsIYNiit1rICccTGZxIwLioqjUNr9kABeVQaCDnFSsCHGDaAxxwjHJKxMbZ7QQHZAzXiFBYiCTSOSKejIXEWIA you can introduce generics to make sure they conform to the same structure. the generics can be extended as well.

Comment: An abstract class definitely makes sense, espescially if the `NotifyInternally` method looks the same in every error notifier.

Answer (score 0):

`How do I ensure that in the constructor of that class also the type and the errors are passed and are available for the notifyInternally method?`

An abstract (generic) class makes the most sense, espescially for this reason.

```
abstract class ErrorNotifierBase<T, U> {
   private m_type: T;
   private m_errors: U
   constructor(a_type: T, a_errors: U){
      this.m_errors = a_errors;
      this.m_type = a_type;
   }

   protected notifyInternally(): void {
      console.log(this.m_type, this.m_errors);
   }
}
```

This abstract class can be used by your different error notifiers:

```
class EmailErrorNotifier extends ErrorNotifierBase<string, string[]> {

   constructor(a_type: string, a_errors: string[]){
     // The base constructor forces the "super" call to the base constructor.
     super(a_type, a_errors);
   }
}
```

If the `m_type` and `m_errors` properties are the same in all of your notifiers, you can also just omit the generics.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgolKB7KAcrhAJYBmJAplAEJqUA8AKgDQICqAfAgN4CwAKATCADlBIA3YBEoIAtgH0IATxGUAXAiYBuQcIRjJ02Yup4oYTez3DYuAHaQoAV3j4AFMCWqNWtl7N8Sw4ASn4hfWEIAAsSMAA6UxwghABeBADki10IyJi4xO81NIyiyhz9AF9BGwM8GXhKABMEe2JyZQBJexkoe2BkZGV3EM0JXBIW8MjbBzBcZEp45FwAc3d8hMUVNTZNwsCLEIrhaoEzwRQ0DEw5YBJkbHMiUgpqBEoADxl7Jpusl7kKi0egMJwkeyrNjgyEAbQAutxwrU7I5oK4IB4vDtfDCoaVDsE8QiwrVhAB6claaKyED0JBzdFuKAIMj4WCUDAxWQAIjAzjUUB5SAGyAQmPFNIQdLAslRTgx+HiZIQ-MFnjK-gUhOOtTOlSAA)

Edit: If you want the actual notifiers to implement the `notifyInternally` method you can make the base method `abstract` and let the notifier implement it.